# Azure PowerShell - See tags assigned to resource

Tags: powershell, azure, tags, azure-automation

What I'd like to do is pull up a list of tags that are assigned to a resource.

I see that I can use this syntax to pull up resources based on a name/value pair.  Also, if I leave out the value, it will return all tags with that name.

```
Get-AzureResource -Tag @{ Name="";Value="" }
```

I'd like to set up some automation stuff, for example: based on the value, start or stop a resource at various points of the day.

I do not see any cmdlets for doing what I am trying to do.  Any advice?

Comment: How you solve your automation problem will depend very much on the service you are targetting (websites, web roles, SQL DB, etc).  This is a pretty broad question to be honest!  Resouce Manager Cmdlets (like the one you have here) are slightly different to the ones you use to manage resources.  As a basic approach: you will have to pull out the resource identifier (name) and type (website) and then find the right PS Cmdlet to manage that resource type (Stop-AzureWebsite for example).

Comment: Yes, I understand that part.  What I am attempting to do, however, is invoke those cmdlet's (i.e. Stop-AzureWebsite) based on the tags assigned to that site.  The API doesn't seem to have any cmdlet's to pull the tags for any specific resource, regardless of whether you use the AzureResourceManager or the AzureServiceManagement cmdlets.

Comment: your question is still not clear... please elaborate